# How to create media player using slimdx

Tags: c#-3.0, multimedia, slimdx

How we will code a media player using slimdx n c# coding

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try borrowing [this guy's code](http://www.planet-source-code.com/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?txtCodeId=7304&lngWId=10)... you'll have to translate it from VB but appears most of what you're looking for is there.

Comment: That article mentions SlimDX/DirectX but the source actually uses DirectShow